# Pulling from multiple tables, with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql

Background: I'm working on a project where I am updating an internal site that was put together sometime around 2006 or so (maybe even earlier, I can't quite tell). I'm moving the "print reports" functions to a web based platform and away from ODBC drivers that allow reports to be created and printed from Microsoft Access.

Because they want only specific information available in each report (else I'd pull in all the data and just have them sort it by desired column themselves) I've turned the queries into views, and the php queries the view, and then formats the tabular data.

This worked for a view in which I was pulling data from three tables and had two joins:

Tables: accents, hunters, leprechauns. Joins are just to pull in the names of the hunters and the leprechauns so those display instead of their ID numbers.

```
SELECT 
 CONCAT(LEFT(a.red_id,1),'-',RIGHT(a.red_id,5)) AS red
, a.orange
, a.yellow
, a.green
, a.blue
, DATE_FORMAT(a.color_begin, '%m/%d/%y') AS color_start
, DATE_FORMAT(a.color_end, '%m/%d/%y') AS color_end
, DATE_FORMAT(a.rainbow_begin, '%m/%d/%y') AS rainbow_start
, DATE_FORMAT(a.rainbow_end, '%m/%d/%y') AS rainbow_end
, SUBSTRING(l.lastname FROM 1 FOR 10) as leprechaun
, SUBSTRING(a.keywords FROM 1 FOR 25) as keyword
, CONCAT(h.firstname, ' ', h.lastname) AS treasureHunter
, a.indigo
, CONCAT(LEFT(a.color_rate * 100, 2), '%') as color_percent
, a.violet  
FROM accents a
JOIN hunters h ON a.treasureHunter_id = h.hunter_id
JOIN leprechauns l ON a.leprechauns_id = l.leprechauns_id
WHERE rainbow_end >= sysdate() - INTERVAL 90 day
AND 
LEFT(red_id, 1) ='5'
ORDER BY a.red_id ASC;
```

This works as it should, and the results display on the screen appropriately.

---

Next, I'm pulling from the accent table, but this time, I need to get the acronym of the brand of paintColor that is used for any given record. So I'm pulling from a few different tables:

- accents, leprechauns, paintColors, and brands.
- accents: paintColor_id
- paintColors: paintColor_id, brand_id
- brands: brand_id, acronym

I have this for the query:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(LEFT(a.red_id,1),'-',RIGHT(a.red_id,5)) AS red
, DATE_FORMAT(a.rainbow_end, '%m/%d/%y') AS rainbow_end
, SUBSTRING(l.lastname FROM 1 FOR 10) as leprechaun
, SUBSTRING(a.keywords FROM 1 FOR 25) as keyword
, b.acronym
, a.pink
FROM accent a
JOIN leprechauns l ON a.leprechauns_id = l.leprechauns_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN paintColors p ON a.paintColor_id = p.paintColor_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN brands b ON b.brand_id = p.brand_id
WHERE a.paintColor_id = p.paintColor_id
AND a.active = '1'
AND rainbow_end >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
AND LEFT(a.red_id, 1) = '5'
ORDER BY b.acronym ASC;
```

This query works from the MySQL standpoint; I use workbench and in the GUI results are returned properly.

However the web page is throwing me some errors, which is making me wonder if this query is written as well as it could be. The php is the same code I used for the above query, I select the view, pull the results, and loop through the results to create the rows of tabular data.

Error Messages:

1. mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
   resource
2. mysql_fetch_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

My specific question: since it has to be the two LEFT OUTER JOINS that are causing the issue, can those two joins (and the WHERE clause) be written in a better way that will not cause the error?

EDIT TO ADD: The code is great. It was something else entirely!

Comment: what var_dump(mysql_query(//your query here)) returns?

Comment: Try echoing out `mysql_error()` too  that will let you see what error is being passed back from the database.

Comment: Hmm why do you think the joins are the issue, if the query works on the server then whatever is being called to run the query is dropping the ball I assume.

Comment: @UselessIntern yup. Issue wasn't with the code at all.